# Lollipop update on Moto G XT1033

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I check my Moto G XT1033 phone on daily basis hoping that one day I will get Android 5.0. But I didn't haven't got the update yet.

Is there any current expected date it will be released in India?

Answer (score 0):

According to this post on 1/4/15:

> NEW DELHI: Motorola reveals that the Android 5.0 update is about to release for the Moto G and then a member of the XDA Developers said that they had got the update in India for their Moto G XT1033.

They said that the version number is 220.21.16.en.03 and this is the official version. So it looks as though India has been the first region to get the Moto G update. This makes the device one of the most affordable that has the latest OS. The update is already getting rolled out in other regions."

Looks like it will be any day now, no exact date can be given as these updates are rolled out in bunches and might hit your neighbor before you. Just keep checking.

[Source](http://customstoday.com.pk/android-5-0-lollipop-update-for-moto-g-xt1033-27/)